# Distinguish between row click and checkbox selection in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Is there a way to distinguish between row selection via checkbox versus clicking on the row in ag-grid? There's a setting 'suppressRowClickSelection' that can be used to refine the behavior when using checkbox selection but not sure if there's a built in way to actually distinguish between the two events in the grid api. If not, could someone recommend a straightforward way to achieve this?

**Application context:** Grid contains a list of map locations

**Desired behavior:**

1) Clicking on a row will zoom to that location on a map

2) Selecting locations with the checkbox will enable a button "Add Locations to Favorites"

**Software Versions:** ag-grid 15.0 on Angular 5

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/

Comment: But why you don't want use approach which you described. I mean to use 'suppressRowClickSelection' and handle the event (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)' and zoom your map. In the event, you can get params from the clicked row. Where you found which row you clicked. And when you check checkbox you can handle another event (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)" where you can find all needed information about row too.

Comment: I feel silly now. Good call: (rowClicked) and (rowSelected) are the two events I needed! Thanks. I was thinking rowClicked -> rowSelected, but I can treat them separately. Thank you.